# No Schema type for mysql type datetime error while creating view to show webform submissions

Tags: 7, webforms

I am attempting to display webform submitted data in view. For that I have used [Webform MYSQL Views](http://drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views) and [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module. And I am referring tutorial from here: http://drupal.org/node/1658784. The problem is when I created MySQL views for given webform, it has created view with `Submitted` column as `datetime` field.

Now when I go to `Structure > Data Table > Adopt Tables` and selects the created view, it is giving error of "no Schema type for mysql type datetime".

I googled for it, but didn't find any solution yet, any suggestion how can I overcome this error.

-- Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely already resolved this, but I just ran into the same issue.  Here's how I resolved it:

I applied the patches to the Schema module listed here: http://drupal.org/node/1237974.

This got rid of the error, but because i had a db_prefix on my tables, I could not adopt them.  In order to get that working, I tried the patches here (http://drupal.org/node/894074#comment-6459584).  It didn't work for my view, so I logged in via PHPMYAdmin and removed the prefix dr_ from the webform view (instead of dr_webform_myviewname, it's now webform_myviewname).  This allowed me to adopt it.

I'm not saying it was pretty, but it is working now.

KMT